# Python Code within Zapier Zap - Ways to serialize data more effectively?

Tags: python, zapier

Just started with [Zapier](https://zapier.com/help/create/code-webhooks/use-python-code-in-zaps) and building out a few test Zaps to gain a deeper understanding of the capabilities using Zapier for my org.

I've run into a few issues with outputs needing to be serialized. I found a simple fix that passes the output value as a string and it seems to fix the issue in every instance. My question is; does anyone have any suggestions on possibly cleaning this up or a better way so I do not have to output data this way? Is there anything necessarily wrong with performing the script this way?

Not looking for people literally to re-write my code (unless you'd be open to provide tips for a newbie to python) just looking for some best practice advise.

***Code:***

```
import re

emails = re.findall(r'[\w._-]+@[\w._-]+\.[\w._-]+', input_data['Payload'])
url = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', input_data['Payload'])
tid = re.search('(.*) - This',input_data['PayloadText'])


output = [{'Emails': emails,'URLS': url, 'TemplateID': str(tid)}]
```

This snipit here; `'TemplateID': str(tid)` is the code in question.

My output from that snipit is `TemplateID <re.Match object; span=(1059, 1070), match='1283 - This'>`

Please keep in mind I know the script itself could use some hygene!

Thanks for any and all assitance!

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what you want to do with the data in later steps. Feeding a string-ified python regex into another step probably won't be super useful? I might try to pull out the actual tempalte id instead (`1283`). You'll also want to be more defensive in case there isn't a match.

But to answer your root question: no, there's nothing inherently wrong with passing that string between steps. All Zapier sees is a string.